# Multiple (spoken) languages for shell script based locale?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, bsd

I have the situation where I have some zsh scripts that are used for utilities.  I currently have several versions of the scripts, depending on which team is using them.   I would like to have single .sh file that just picks the correct output language based on the locale, and then the messages are in a table or something of sort.  I have been unable to find anything that will get me started on this.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

(note, the languages are multibyte)

Comment: Using `gettext` is probably your best bet unless you want to roll-out your own. Related recent discussion on the zsh-workers mailing list: https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2023/msg00567.html